# Get cx and cy of canvas

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, color-wheel

I am using [this color wheel](https://github.com/bgrins/colorwheel-1k), and I want to change the color of the color wheel programmatically. So if I have a color value (rgb, hsv etc.) I want to change the color wheel to that specific color?

For example, if I have `hsv(150, 100, 1)`, I want the color wheel to change to that.

I already asked the question, but both people that answered, aren't answering the comments, and I don't know how to implement what they wrote. We'll use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322416/5244870) So he said to use the following code:

```
var h = 150;
var s = 100;
currentX = cx - s * radius * Math.cos(PI2 * h);
currentY = cy - s * radius * Math.sin(PI2 * h);
```

> Where cx, cy is the center of the colour wheel.

The question is, how can I define cx and cy? Or if it's already defined in the code, which variable is it?

Comment: (cx,cy) is a common convention for the (x,y) coordinate of the **c**enter. however, given that `h` is in degrees, whereas the `cos` and `sin` are in radians, the trig you have there is quite wrong, those should be `Math.cos(Math.PI * h/180)` and `Math.sin(Math.PI * h/180)`

Comment: So how can I get `cx` and `cy` values?

Comment: ... you already know them. You know the dimensions of your circle (whether you know the radius, or the box the circle fits in) so you *know* the coordinate of the center already.

Comment: So I would do `radius / 2` ?

Comment: For what? the (cx,cy) values? No, with a tight bounding box (cx,cy) is just (radius, radius). Protip (literally): draw your circle on some paper, things get a lot clearer.

Comment: So for the currentX I should do the following? `currentX = radius - s * radius * Math.cos(PI2 * h);

Comment: at this point you're asking questions where you should be writing code. Set cx = radius, and cy = radius, and read what I said about the trigonometry calls being very wrong.